# web based spreadsheet that can access database

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-views

I'm a bit new to web development and wanted some insight on how to approach a project of mine.

We have a large mysql with a fairly large dataset that we want people to be able to play around with.  Is there a way to have some sort of web based spreadsheet that, in addition to do normal spreadsheet calculations, query a database and pull down content? We have niche statical information on companies we research, ideally a user would come to the site and be able to access our data while adding their own logic(math operators) to make it more relevant to them.

We don't want to create an api to connect to their desktops(yet) and want to do this entirely over the web.

Any help on the approach or tools you'd use would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Edit: I found a good tool for drupal "Sheetnode" which uses phpexcel....I'll study it, I'm not totally sure if it allows mysql queries to be added within cells.

Comment: My first response is [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer).

Comment: Thanks for the response Jared.  I don't understand though.  I looked up REST and isn't it just a way of delivering data?  I might be reading into it, but are you suggesting I setup a rest api on my server and allow the webbased excel to query data from it?  I'm not sure, just trying to figure out how this applies to my problem.

Comment: When I do a search for web-based spreadsheet, several options come up, including Google Docs. You might also look into ExtJS. Pretty much what you want is a Javascript frontend with a way to provide data to the browser (in JSON, XML, CSV), or some other means. In that case, a REST service would allow the database connection to be abstracted, so it wouldn't matter what DB was on the backend, but not sure if you could easily allow queries directly from a cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give [YUI datatable](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/) a try. The YUI library is one of the best-documented libraries. Yes, you can do queries for every cell in the sheet. You can use one query to populate the whole spreadsheet, and then another query for updating each individual cell. You will be responsible for programming the server-side code in Drupal using your own custom module. The menu_hook in Drupal will allow you to accept RESTful calls from the datatable and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I found phpexcel ( phpexcel.codeplex.com/ ) does what I want and there's a module for drupal for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with Java, the most relevant choice would probably be https://vaadin.com/spreadsheet and using the open source framework Vaadin (Disclaimer: I'm working for the company behind the tool).

But anyhow, with this it's as easy as:

```
Spreadsheet s = new Spreadsheet(
    new File("/path/to/some/xls/file/on/server.xlsx"));
layout.addComponent(s);
```

to add a excel file in your web browser.